# "Inverted" Timeout functionality in NUnit tests

Tags: nunit, timeout

I'm looking for a way to write a unit test using NUnit so that if current test takes more than X miliseconds to complete it should terminate and report it as skipped / success, but not failed. This would basically be the opposite of the NUnit [Timeout](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) attribute.

A bit of context to the problem: I have some unit tests that invoke remote servers and check their responses. If there is a network issue I don't want the test to fail, I would only want to have that test fail if it was able to get a response and that response was incorrect. The same time if a response doesn't arrive I'd like to move on and skip the test.

(I realize that this approach might result in some errors not being reported, however in m situation I'm looking for no false negatives being reported (e.g. not having a test that succeeds once and fails another time based on network connectivity which I don't intend to test). )

Comment: What if the servers get renamed, or taken permanently offline, or blocked by your firewall software, or...? Your tests would never tell you that they weren't actually testing anything anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to mock the invocation of the remote servers?

Using mocking, you will be able to isolate your unit from its dependencies, and precisely test your the unit itself, how it deals with responses etc, and not worry about the servers at all.

Indeed, you can use mocking to purposely create incorrect responses to see how your unit deals with them, check for any expected exceptions and so on.

Have a look at [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: You're right that the current testing isn't really unit testing but more integration testing. I'm aware of Moq, the legacy code used simply wasn't ready for mocking due to its design. I think the answer is that there's a good reason this is not supported with NUnit or other unit testing frameworks - if you need such a feature you're trying to do something outside of unit testing.